# Is it possible to get the backtrace in the case where "No shared libraries loaded at this time"?

Tags: gdb, shared-libraries, coredump, debug-symbols, backtrace

I'm getting "No shared libraries loaded at this time", when I give "info share" command and I also loaded the symbol file and core on gdb. But generally the coredump should be loaded with the shared libs as per its corresponding application. I have specified the solib-search-path where GDB will look for shared libraries when searching for symbols.

Is it possible to get the backtrace in the case where "No shared libraries loaded at this time"?

```
gdb>info sharedlibrary
No shared libraries loaded at this time.
gdb> bt
#0  0xb6d1f232 in ?? ()
#1  0xb6d25ddc in ?? ()
#2  0xb6d25ddc in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

Thanks a lot, in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm getting "No shared libraries loaded at this time"

The most frequent cause: binary mismatch.

Let's define host as the machine where you are running GDB, and target as the machine on which the core dump happened.

- If host == target, you may have given GDB the main executable that does not match the executable that crashed, or
- system libraries (and `libc` in particular) have been updated, or
- host != target and system libraries differ between host and target.

> I have specified the `solib-search-path`

Specifying `solib-search-path` after you loaded the `core` doesn't work. Do this instead:

```
gdb ./a.out
(gdb) set solib-search-path /path/to/libs
(gdb) core core  # load core *after* setting solib-search-path
```

Using `set verbose on` may help show exactly which libraries GDB is trying to load (if any).