# gdb core dump: info shared shows nothing

Tags: arm, gdb, coredump

I have a core dump (created by application running on arm platform) which shows no shared library information (info shared yields no results):

```
(gdb) info shared
No shared libraries loaded at this time.
```

It seems to me that core file has the information about shared libraries (<strike>how to verify it?</strike> confirmed with eu-readelf) and it is just GDB that is not able to read them. I'm using GDB (v 8.3.1) from the same ARM toolchain that was used to build the application. It can read the core and executable but without the shared library information I can't map the memory properly so this makes the core file pretty much useless.

main info secion output looks like:

```
Exec file:
    `app', file type elf32-littlearm.
 [0]     0x0154->0x016d at 0x00000154: .interp ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [1]     0x0170->0x0194 at 0x00000170: .note.gnu.build-id ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [2]     0x0194->0x01b4 at 0x00000194: .note.ABI-tag ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [3]     0x01b4->0x05b4 at 0x000001b4: .gnu.hash ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [4]     0x05b4->0x2aa4 at 0x000005b4: .dynsym ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [5]     0x2aa4->0x71f7 at 0x00002aa4: .dynstr ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [6]     0x71f8->0x7696 at 0x000071f8: .gnu.version ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [7]     0x7698->0x78c8 at 0x00007698: .gnu.version_r ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [8]     0x78c8->0xf450 at 0x000078c8: .rel.dyn ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [9]     0xf450->0x10118 at 0x0000f450: .rel.plt ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [10]     0x10118->0x10124 at 0x00010118: .init ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
 [11]     0x10124->0x11470 at 0x00010124: .plt ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
 [12]     0x11470->0x273c34 at 0x00011470: .text ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
 [13]     0x273c34->0x273c3c at 0x00273c34: .fini ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
 [14]     0x273c40->0x32ea4c at 0x00273c40: .rodata ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [15]     0x32ea4c->0x353744 at 0x0032ea4c: .ARM.extab ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [16]     0x353744->0x36bc7c at 0x00353744: .ARM.exidx ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [17]     0x36bc7c->0x36bc80 at 0x0036bc7c: .eh_frame ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [18]     0x37c544->0x37c564 at 0x0036c544: .init_array ALLOC LOAD DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [19]     0x37c564->0x37c568 at 0x0036c564: .fini_array ALLOC LOAD DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [20]     0x37c568->0x37fea4 at 0x0036c568: .data.rel.ro ALLOC LOAD DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [21]     0x37fea4->0x37fffc at 0x0036fea4: .dynamic ALLOC LOAD DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [22]     0x380000->0x380fe8 at 0x00370000: .got ALLOC LOAD DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [23]     0x380fe8->0x3bbf5c at 0x00370fe8: .data ALLOC LOAD DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [24]     0x3bbf60->0x2443fc0 at 0x003abf5c: .bss ALLOC
 [25]     0x0000->0x0011 at 0x003abf5c: .comment READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
 [26]     0x0000->0x0039 at 0x003abf6d: .ARM.attributes READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
 [27]     0x0000->0x21da0 at 0x003abfa8: .debug_aranges READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
 [28]     0x0000->0x4b9ac1 at 0x003cdd48: .debug_info READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
 [29]     0x0000->0x1603d at 0x00887809: .debug_abbrev READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
 [30]     0x0000->0x100933 at 0x0089d846: .debug_line READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
 [31]     0x0000->0xc33c8 at 0x0099e17c: .debug_frame READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
 [32]     0x0000->0x11be8b6 at 0x00a61544: .debug_str READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
 [33]     0x0000->0x0b31 at 0x01c1fdfa: .debug_loc READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
 [34]     0x0000->0x250c0 at 0x01c20930: .debug_ranges READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
Core file:
    `app.core', file type elf32-littlearm.
 [0]     0x0000->0x0e68 at 0x000009d4: note0 READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
 [1]     0x0000->0x0048 at 0x00000a30: .reg/14597 HAS_CONTENTS
 [2]     0x0000->0x0048 at 0x00000a30: .reg HAS_CONTENTS
 [3]     0x0000->0x0080 at 0x00000b20: .note.linuxcore.siginfo/14597 HAS_CONTENTS
 [4]     0x0000->0x0080 at 0x00000b20: .note.linuxcore.siginfo HAS_CONTENTS
 [5]     0x0000->0x0098 at 0x00000bb4: .auxv HAS_CONTENTS
 [6]     0x0000->0x07f4 at 0x00000c60: .note.linuxcore.file/14597 HAS_CONTENTS
 [7]     0x0000->0x07f4 at 0x00000c60: .note.linuxcore.file HAS_CONTENTS
 [8]     0x0000->0x0074 at 0x00001468: .reg2/14597 HAS_CONTENTS
 [9]     0x0000->0x0074 at 0x00001468: .reg2 HAS_CONTENTS
 [10]     0x0000->0x0104 at 0x000014f0: .reg-arm-vfp/14597 HAS_CONTENTS
 [11]     0x0000->0x0104 at 0x000014f0: .reg-arm-vfp HAS_CONTENTS
 [12]     0x0000->0x0048 at 0x00001650: .reg/14608 HAS_CONTENTS
 [13]     0x0000->0x0074 at 0x000016b0: .reg2/14608 HAS_CONTENTS
 [14]     0x0000->0x0104 at 0x00001738: .reg-arm-vfp/14608 HAS_CONTENTS
 [15]     0x412000->0x412000 at 0x00002000: load1 ALLOC READONLY CODE
 [16]     0x78e000->0x792000 at 0x00002000: load2 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
 [17]     0x792000->0x7ce000 at 0x00006000: load3 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
 [18]     0x7ce000->0x28d1000 at 0x00042000: load4 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
 [19]     0x6a9c8000->0x6aa8c000 at 0x02145000: load5 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
 [20]     0x6cfbd000->0x6cfed000 at 0x02209000: load6 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
 [21]     0x6cffe000->0x76000000 at 0x02239000: load7 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
 [22]     0x76000000->0x76021000 at 0x0b23b000: load8 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
 [23]     0x76021000->0x76021000 at 0x0b25c000: load9 ALLOC READONLY
 ...more entries follow (removed for this post)
```

not to mention that any attempt to retrieve backtrace looks like

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x76967d16 in ?? ()
#1  0x769e2a30 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be here?

**edit**: eu-readelf --notes app.core yields:

```
eu-readelf --notes app.core 

Segment notatki o długości 3688 B pod offsetem 0x9d4:
  Właściciel     Rozmiar danych  Typ
  CORE                 148  PRSTATUS
    info.si_signo: 11, info.si_code: 0, info.si_errno: 0, cursig: 11
    sigpend: <>
    sighold: <>
    pid: 14597, ppid: 4103, pgrp: 14597, sid: 4103
    utime: 3.290000, stime: 4.900000, cutime: 0.000000, cstime: 0.000000
    orig_r0: 0, fpvalid: 1
    r0:           10  r1:   2127907444  r2:      7938048  r3:   2127906060
    r4:            4  r5:   2127905872  r6:   1990519627  r7:      4814896
    r8:           10  r9:   2127907444  r10:     7938048  r11:  2127907068
    r12:         142  sp:   0x7ed54880  lr:   0x769e2a31  pc:   0x76967d16
    spsr:  0x80070030
  CORE                 124  PRPSINFO
    state: 0, sname: R, zomb: 0, nice: 0, flag: 0x00400600
    uid: 0, gid: 0, pid: 14597, ppid: 4103, pgrp: 14597, sid: 4103
    fname: app, psargs: /tmp/app 
  CORE                 128  SIGINFO
    si_signo: 11, si_errno: 0, si_code: 0
    sender PID: 14597, sender UID: 0
  CORE                 152  AUXV
    HWCAP: 0x8b0d6  <half thumb fast-mult vfp edsp>
    PAGESZ: 4096
    CLKTCK: 100
    PHDR: 0x412034
    PHENT: 32
    PHNUM: 9
    BASE: 0x76f9c000
    FLAGS: 0
    ENTRY: 0x423471
    UID: 0
    EUID: 0
    GID: 0
    EGID: 0
    SECURE: 0
    RANDOM: 0x7ed54dc3
    26
    EXECFN: 0x7ed54ff0
    PLATFORM: 0x7ed54dd3
    NULL
  CORE                2036  FILE
    58 files:
      00412000-0077e000 00000000 3588096             /tmp/app
      0078e000-00792000 0036c000 16384               /tmp/app
      00792000-007ce000 00370000 245760              /tmp/app
      7693a000-7693c000 00000000 8192                /lib/libdl-2.30.so
      7693c000-7694b000 00002000 61440               /lib/libdl-2.30.so
      7694b000-7694c000 00001000 4096                /lib/libdl-2.30.so
      7694c000-7694d000 00002000 4096                /lib/libdl-2.30.so
      7694d000-76a2b000 00000000 909312              /lib/libc-2.30.so
      76a2b000-76a3a000 000de000 61440               /lib/libc-2.30.so
      76a3a000-76a3c000 000dd000 8192                /lib/libc-2.30.so
      76a3c000-76a3e000 000df000 8192                /lib/libc-2.30.so
      76a40000-76a52000 00000000 73728               /lib/libpthread-2.30.so
      76a52000-76a61000 00012000 61440               /lib/libpthread-2.30.so
      76a61000-76a62000 00011000 4096                /lib/libpthread-2.30.so
      76a62000-76a63000 00012000 4096                /lib/libpthread-2.30.so
      76a65000-76a7d000 00000000 98304               /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
      76a7d000-76a8c000 00018000 61440               /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
      76a8c000-76a8d000 00017000 4096                /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
      76a8d000-76a8e000 00018000 4096                /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
      76a8e000-76ae4000 00000000 352256              /lib/libm-2.30.so
      76ae4000-76af3000 00056000 61440               /lib/libm-2.30.so
      76af3000-76af4000 00055000 4096                /lib/libm-2.30.so
      76af4000-76af5000 00056000 4096                /lib/libm-2.30.so
      76af5000-76c1c000 00000000 1208320             /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.27
      76c1c000-76c2c000 00127000 65536               /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.27
      76c2c000-76c33000 00127000 28672               /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.27
      76c33000-76c34000 0012e000 4096                /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.27
      76c35000-76c3e000 00000000 36864               /apps/app/lib/libunwind.so.8
      76c3e000-76c4d000 00009000 61440               /apps/app/lib/libunwind.so.8
      76c4d000-76c4e000 00008000 4096                /apps/app/lib/libunwind.so.8
      76c4e000-76c4f000 00009000 4096                /apps/app/lib/libunwind.so.8
      76c68000-76c83000 00000000 110592              /apps/app/lib/libtid.so
      76c83000-76c93000 0001b000 65536               /apps/app/lib/libtid.so
      76c93000-76c94000 0001b000 4096                /apps/app/lib/libtid.so
      76c94000-76c95000 0001c000 4096                /apps/app/lib/libtid.so
      76c95000-76e1c000 00000000 1601536             /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1
      76e1c000-76e2b000 00187000 61440               /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1
      76e2b000-76e42000 00186000 94208               /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1
      76e42000-76e43000 0019d000 4096                /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1
      76e47000-76e93000 00000000 311296              /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.1
      76e93000-76ea3000 0004c000 65536               /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.1
      76ea3000-76ea8000 0004c000 20480               /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.1
      76ea8000-76eab000 00051000 12288               /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.1
      76eab000-76eb4000 00000000 36864               /apps/app/lib/libtidc.so
      76eb4000-76ec3000 00009000 61440               /apps/app/lib/libtidc.so
      76ec3000-76ec4000 00008000 4096                /apps/app/lib/libtidc.so
      76ec4000-76ec5000 00009000 4096                /apps/app/lib/libtidc.so
      76ec5000-76f68000 00000000 667648              /usr/lib/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
      76f68000-76f77000 000a3000 61440               /usr/lib/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
      76f77000-76f79000 000a2000 8192                /usr/lib/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
      76f79000-76f7b000 000a4000 8192                /usr/lib/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
      76f7b000-76f8a000 00000000 61440               /lib/libz.so.1.2.11
      76f8a000-76f9a000 0000f000 65536               /lib/libz.so.1.2.11
      76f9a000-76f9b000 0000f000 4096                /lib/libz.so.1.2.11
      76f9b000-76f9c000 00010000 4096                /lib/libz.so.1.2.11
      76f9c000-76fb5000 00000000 102400              /lib/ld-2.30.so
      76fc4000-76fc5000 00018000 4096                /lib/ld-2.30.so
      76fc5000-76fc6000 00019000 4096                /lib/ld-2.30.so
  CORE                 116  FPREGSET
    f0: 0x000000000000000000000000  f1: 0x000000000000000000000000
    f2: 0x000000000000000000000000  f3: 0x000000000000000000000000
    f4: 0x000000000000000000000000  f5: 0x000000000000000000000000
    f6: 0x000000000000000000000000  f7: 0x000000000000000000000000
  LINUX                260  ARM_VFP
    fpscr: 0x656e6e6f
    d0:  0x64657463656e6e6f  d1:  0x0000000000000000
    d2:  0x0000000000000000  d3:  0x0000000000000000
    d4:  0x0000000000000000  d5:  0x0000000000000000
    d6:  0x0000000000000000  d7:  0x0000000000000000
    d8:  0x0000000000000000  d9:  0x0000000000000000
    d10: 0x0000000000000000  d11: 0x0000000000000000
    d12: 0x0000000000000000  d13: 0x0000000000000000
    d14: 0x0000000000000000  d15: 0x0000000000000000
    d16: 0xffffffffffffffff  d17: 0x4059000000000000
    d18: 0x412e848000000000  d19: 0x0000000000000000
    d20: 0x0000000000000000  d21: 0x0000000000000000
    d22: 0x0000000000000000  d23: 0x0000000000000000
    d24: 0x0000000000000000  d25: 0x0000000000000000
    d26: 0x0000000000000000  d27: 0x0000000000000000
    d28: 0x0000000000000000  d29: 0x0000000000000000
    d30: 0x0000000000000000  d31: 0x0000000000000000
  CORE                 148  PRSTATUS
    info.si_signo: 11, info.si_code: 0, info.si_errno: 0, cursig: 11
    sigpend: <>
    sighold: <>
    pid: 14608, ppid: 4103, pgrp: 14597, sid: 4103
    utime: 0.330000, stime: 0.420000, cutime: 0.000000, cstime: 0.000000
    orig_r0: 8183760, fpvalid: 1
    r0:      8183760  r1:          128  r2:            0  r3:            0
    r4:      8183760  r5:      8183720  r6:            0  r7:          240
    r8:            0  r9:            0  r10:  1989361680  r11:           0
    r12:         240  sp:   0x76933fe0  lr:   0x76a4bd29  pc:   0x76a50b24
    spsr:  0x800f0030
  CORE                 116  FPREGSET
    f0: 0x000000000000000000000000  f1: 0x000000000000000000000000
    f2: 0x000000000000000000000000  f3: 0x000000000000000000000000
    f4: 0x000000000000000000000000  f5: 0x000000000000000000000000
    f6: 0x000000000000000000000000  f7: 0x000000000000000000000000
  LINUX                260  ARM_VFP
    fpscr: 0x6f662067
    d0:  0x756d20726f662067  d1:  0x223a226449746669
    d2:  0xa52c550358ebcb70  d3:  0x673aecbbd5d48f94
    d4:  0x8e24e4fea9d1060d  d5:  0x1e3d32fb3006e21d
    d6:  0x447a0000f9a47218  d7:  0x0000000000000000
    d8:  0x0000000000000000  d9:  0x0000000000000000
    d10: 0x0000000000000000  d11: 0x0000000000000000
    d12: 0x0000000000000000  d13: 0x0000000000000000
    d14: 0x0000000000000000  d15: 0x0000000000000000
    d16: 0x0000000000000000  d17: 0x0000000000000000
    d18: 0x0000000000000000  d19: 0x0000000000000000
    d20: 0x0000000000000000  d21: 0x0000000000000000
    d22: 0x0000000000000000  d23: 0x0000000000000000
    d24: 0x0000000000000000  d25: 0x0000000000000000
    d26: 0x0000000000000000  d27: 0x0000000000000000
    d28: 0x0000000000000000  d29: 0x0000000000000000
    d30: 0x0000000000000000  d31: 0x0000000000000000
```

which confirms the information is there in the core file.

Comment: Did gdb not write any errors or warnings when loading the core file?

Comment: No, everything reads just fine. No error messager nor warnings.
I was also able to confirm with eu-readelf that shared library mapping is in the core. So it's definitely a GDB issue.

Comment: Did you see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29813448/1983398)? Especially that part about `host != target and system libraries differ between host and target` might apply here.

Comment: How did you invoke GDB? This answer may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20998804/50617

Comment: I have same problem that core dump no shared library on mips cpu. did you solve this ?